# Approximation of $ n^a \int_{0}^{\pi/n}\sin^b(t)dt $

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

How can I find an approximation of $$ n^a \int_{0}^{\pi/n}\sin^b(t)dt $$ when $ n\rightarrow \infty$, $(a,b>0)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\sin(t)\sim t$ when $t\to0$, the integral is equivalent to 
$$
\left[(b+1)^{-1}t^{b+1}\right]_0^{\pi/n}=(b+1)^{-1}(\pi/n)^{b+1},
$$ 
and the equivalent you are looking for is $\pi^{b+1}(b+1)^{-1}n^{a-b-1}$.